# Does an Observable necessarily complete when it emits data?

Tags: rxjs

When working with `rxjs`, I often subscribe to my source Observable and using the `onData` and `onError` handlers, attach some logic to take care of each case. That looks something like:

```
this.myService.myObservable().subscribe(
    () => this.onNextData(),
    () => this.onErrorData()
);
```

Then (and sometimes), inside of each of the handlers, I will do the same logic, say, close a modal on success *and* on failure.

I saw that there is a `finalize` operator that I can pipe that will execute some logic based on `onComplete` and `onError`. However, are both of these states the same? Does an Observable necessarily `complete` when it emits data?

Example:

```
this.myService.myObservable()
    // modalClose always happens on success and on failure (?)
    .pipe(finalize(() => this.modalClose())
    .subscribe(
        () => this.onNextData(),
        () => this.onErrorData()
);
```

Comment: In addition to the great answer, I have an example of an "action" stream that does not complete here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-todos-deborahk The `userSelectedAction$` Observable emits each time the user selects a user from a drop down. This Observable never completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an Observable does not necessarily `complete` when it emits data.

Observables, unlike promises, are explicitly designed for multiple emissions - so it makes no sense for them to always `complete` after a single emission.

Think of the `complete` as the Observable saying "I will never send you more data".

For a very common use-case like making a web request - it is normal that it will either emit a value or an error once and then `complete`.

For a different use-case such as one part of the application communicating to another - it is normal that it will send multiple messages and only `complete` when the source is removed.

---

From the [documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable):

> Observables are lazy Push collections of multiple values. They fill
>   the missing spot in the following table:

[image: table]